# Elegant detection of ActivityIndicator start/stop Animating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

The application at hand has several viewControllers stacked in UINavigation.

Each View can call internal actions that will fires individual Activity Indicator (one Activity Indicator per view).

**Question:** What is an elegant way to have a central code that can detect when the different activity Indicators are starting / Stopping ?

I assume a good central point would be the delegate, I am looking for a solution which is clean, efficient and above all elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the activity indicator view in your delegate and add it such that it is always at the front of your views and hide it.

Create a counter in your delegate's interface
`int activityCounter;`

Create a method on your delegate for example

```
-(void)startActivityIndicator {
    activityCounter++;
    activityView.hidden = NO;
}
```

And another for finishing

```
-(void)stopActivityIndicator {
    activityCounter--;
    if (activityCounter <= 0)
        activityView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Then in your view controllers when you start an activity that needs to display the indicator, you can call `startActivityIndicator` on your delegate and when it has finished, call `stopActivityIndicator`. This will also handle the cases where you might have more than one overlapping activity and you want to keep the activity indicator visible until they have all finished.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create a generalized View Controller for all the View controllers and inherit it in all the Views in which you are firing activity indicators...

Then you can maintain your stack of the activity indicators according to your views. You can store an NSMutableArray to keep track of the activity indicators yo're starting and stoping.

Another way is you can also use NSMutableDictionary, so that you can store your activity indicator's flag along with its parent view as its key.

All the best!!!